# How to search for a certain file recursively and overwrite?

Tags: linux, shell, recursion, command-line, copy

Linux, command line.

I have a certain file named file.txt.
It is contained in multiple folders within a certain path, let's say /path/.
For example I have /path/folder1/file.tx and /path/folder2/folder/file.txt

I must substitute all these occurences with a new file.txt that is in /path2/.

Comment: Using what programming language? On what platform?

Answer (score 1):

I am also not sure in which environment you want to perform this. With a linux filesystem and tools, this should work:

`find /path -name file.txt -exec cp -rf /path2/file.txt {} \;`